# UITableViewController celulas ficam em branco/Somem ao rolar a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Estou tendo um problema com a minha tableviewcontroller, conforme eu atualizo algum dado em um textfield ou rolo pra baixo ela vai sumindo com algumas celulas, se eu rolar para cima e para baixo ocultando a celula que sumiu ela volta a aparecer como se tivesse recarregado, ja tentei dar reload toda vez que edito mas nao funciona ?  alguem ja teve algo semelhante ? estou usando uma celula customizada

meu cellforRowAt esta assim

```
fieldValues = metadataBuilder.fieldValues
return metadataBuilder.cells[indexPath.row]
```

metadatabuilder e um objeto com um array de uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O funcionamento de uma UITableView pode ser resumido como uma lista que carrega somente os dados necessários (os que estão sendo mostrados) enquanto remove da memória células que já foram  carregadas e somem da tela, como no seu caso onde o valor dentro da UITextField de uma célula se perde ao sair de exibição da tela.

O funcionamento descrito por você somente é alcançado se você guardar o valor do UITextField e novamente atribuir o valor quando a célula for inicializada no *cellForRow*.

Algo similar a isto:

```
func cellForRow(at: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {
     ...
     cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.textField.delegate = self
     cell.textField.text = self.arrayDeValores[indexPath.row]
     ...
     return cell
}
```

Quanto a parte de salvar os textos inseridos na array você precisará implementar [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) para cada um para então:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
     self.arrayDeValores[textField.tag] = textField.text ?? ""
}
```

Não esqueça de declarar a array como uma variável do escopo da classe. A propriedade [tag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) é utilizada para identificação da textfield correta.

Comment: Opa consegui resolver e cabei esquecendo de postar aqui, mas creio que essa solução ae também funcione no meu caso eu salvei um array com o tamanho de cada celula pra poder setar no heighForRowAt, aparentemente ele colocava um tamanho menor pra celula e ela não aparecia, mas Obrigado pela atenção jovem